# Am I eligible to migrate as skilled worker?

Tags: australia, technology, brazilian-citizens

I am 28 years old, Brazilian and I graduated last year (February 2013, to be more exactly) as a Bachelor in Computer Science. I'm reading about the migration process and I want to migrate to Australia for example (but I also considered other destinations as well).

I've read some news about the need for skilled people in my area (technology - software developer), recently.

- I would like to know: Am I eligible to migrate as a skilled worker?
- Is it necessary to have more years of work experience in the area?
- Is there an other way to migrate to these countries?
- My point is that I have a Bachelor in Computer Science, and that should mean something, right?

I'm working in the area some 3 years already, mainly as a freelancer, but from this officialy only for 9 months (since I finished the college), and I had to quit because of my mom health problems.

Is there any hope for me?

Answer (score 10):

There are multiple ways you can obtain permanent residency (PR) in Australia. Pathways to PR will generally fall into 3 categories:

### 1. Skilled Independent

You could obtain a [Skilled Independent](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/189.aspx) visa directly.

You will have to pass a points test that will rank you based on occupation, education level, age, English language ability, years of work experience, etc.

To know more about the points-based system for Skilled Independent migration, refer to [SkillSelect](http://www.immi.gov.au/Work/Pages/SkillSelect/SkillSelect.aspx).

Part 3 of [this document](http://www.immi.gov.au/allforms/pdf/1119.pdf) describes the points system in detail. The current points pass mark, required to be able to apply, is 60. Use [this calculator](http://www.harriswake.com/skillselectpointscalculator) to estimate your points. After you have established you have 60 points, you should submit an Expression of Interest. Every month the department invites people to apply, based on a ranking of those who submitted an EoI.

### 2. Employer sponsorship

You could try a sponsorship by an Australian employer under the [Employer Nomination Scheme](http://www.immi.gov.au/Visas/Pages/186.aspx).

You will need to get an employer that's willing to sponsor you for a permanent visa. Not many employers directly sponsor employees for a PR. It's far more common to be first sponsored for a temporary work visa.

### 3. Temporary to permanent pathway

You can obtain a temporary visa (work or study) first and applying for PR later.

This option is useful if you are not directly eligible for the other 2 options. Spending time working or studying in Australia increases your chances of obtaining a PR. Having a degree from an Australian institution or Australian work experience will give you more points.

---

These 3 options are not necessarily mutually exclusive. You could try to obtain a temporary visa while you sort out the application for a skilled independent visa, or even after applying, while your application is being processed. However, both options will take quite a lot of effort and especially, money. I would first check for eligibility under SkillSelect, and submit an Expression of Interest.

### Skilled Occupation List

The skills that are in high demand in Australia are listed in the [Skilled Occupation List (SOL)](http://www.immi.gov.au/Work/Pages/skilled-occupations-lists/skilled-occupations-lists.aspx). Several software development professions are in the list.

### Skills assessment

In addition to satisfying the required work experience of the points system, you will need to satisfy the assessment of a professional body, which might have its own work experience requirement. In your case, the [Australian Computer Society (ACS)](http://www.acs.org.au/migration-skills-assessment) will do the assessment. In all cases, work experience needs to be proven. Any experience you plan to claim, e.g. your freelance work or job, will need to be substantiated by documentation. These may include payslips, employer letter, receipts, tax documents. These things have to be done before you submit an EoI.

Comment: Wow @Will, thank you so much! You certainly gave me some hope my friend! About the options that you listed I will try it the first option for now. If it doesn't work, can apply myself for the third category too ? I'm afraid to apply the first category and wait a lot , because of the normal bureaucracy, to apply myself for the third category. What you think that I should do now ?

Comment: @ValterHenrique I edited the answer to clarify some points. Please let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you are not eligible to apply for migration to Australia at the moment. Before you can be eligible you will have to have a skills assessment in your IT occupation. This would done be the Australian Computer Society. They require between 2 and 8 years work experience in a job that is highly related to your qualifications. In your case it would probably be 2 or 3 years work experience before you can be deemed skilled.

Note that you can only earn work experience points one your are deemed skilled.

Answer (score 1):

Australia has points-based immigration system, so you can calculate your points and chance to pass.

http://www.workpermit.com/australia/point_calculator.htm - for Australia.

This is of course just a start, you need to do much more of your own research about both Australia and other countries with immigration based on points, like Canada and I think New Zealand. USA has much more complicated system, not based on points.

Comment: Thank you @Peter! As I said, my biggest corcern is about my lack of experience, officialy speaking. And what you mean about my skills be competitive ? For that I believe so, it's not everyone that have a bachelor in computer science right ? :)