# How can I begin my career abroad?

Tags: working-visas

I'm from Malaysia, 21 and my B.s.c in computing is expected to complete next year. I can speak English and Mandarin. How do I start my career abroad? What is the best place for computer science guys?

Comment: This is a very, very broad question.  It differs depending on country, goal, contracting or full time, and more. It's also subjective - "what is the best place".  As it stands we'll need to put the question on hold, but do edit it after having a read of the [help] and vote to reopen when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having a degree, you are in a good position to apply for a work visa in another country. Typically you would go to the web page for the immigration department of the country you are interested in, and explore the options available to you. It is almost always easier to get a work visa if you have a job offer from a company, and you might have to travel to do an in-person interview. You probably already have an idea about what part of the world you might like to go, which would help narrow down your choices.

For example, in New Zealand you would probably be eligible for a [work visa](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/worktemporarily/) if you have a job offer. A [working holiday visa](http://www.immigration.govt.nz/migrant/stream/work/workingholiday/malaysiaworkingholidayscheme.htm) might be a good way to explore New Zealand with the ability to work (but I see that the number of places available for Malaysian nationals is limited).

Comment: Too bad to be limited